# How could I edit at the same time the GridView and DetailsView

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I´m working with a detailsView ans a GridView, within the DetailsView I have the ModeChanging event that allows the fields to be editable, I´d like that when I click on the modify button also allows edit the GridView fields without of the AutoGenerateEditbutton attribute, so that with this I could edit at the same time the DetailsView and GridView.

Is this possible?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `EditIndex` of your `GridView` to the row you want to edit on the modechange event of the detailsview. And remember to `DataBind()`.